# Creating a Line Graph using ggplot

Tags: r

I am brand new at using R code. I am trying to produce a line graph. Here is my code:

```
ggplot(data = legosets, mapping = aes(x = num_sets, y = Year)) +
  geom_line()
```

Unfortunately it is producing an error which reads

> Error in FUN(X[[I]], ...) : object 'num_sets' not found Calls:  ...  -> f -> scales_add_defaults -> apply -> FUN execution halted

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: Can you post first few rows of `legosets` ? Do you have column named `num_sets` and `Year` in it? What does `names(legosets)` return?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is about the legosets data in the lego package : https://github.com/seankross/lego/blob/master/data-tidy/legosets.csv

You can find the variables in there here: https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/lego/versions/0.1.1/topics/legosets

I assume you need to replace `num_sets` by `Pieces`, but you need to read the variable dexcription yourself to confirm that.